# listing mysql tables starting with a particular letter

Tags: mysql

How to list all tables in MYSQL DB starting with "T"?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming MySQL 5.0:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'T%'
```

Here's the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)

Answer (score 7):

The true ANSI way:

```
SELECT  TABLE_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE   TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T%'
```

Doesn't assume the presence or behaviour of the USE function. This should work in every DBMS supporting the ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, which definitely includes MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'T%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
show tables from db_name like 't%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this inside mysql shell program:

use information_schema;
select table_name from tables where table_name like 't%';